# Interrupt exit transition in D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I've got a D3 force layout network with labeled links like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mzur/b30b932d1b9544644abd). I've extended it so the exiting link labels have a fadeout effect. The exit code of the labels looks like this:

```
$linkLabel.exit()
   .classed('fadeout', true)
   .transition()
   .delay(250)
   .remove();
```

Now it's possible for a label to re-enter the layout while still fading/exiting (e.g. when quick successive mouseover and mouseout events occur on the same node). What happens is that the respective label is removed anyway because the event flow is like `exit()` -> `transition()` -> `delay()` -> `enter()` -> `remove()`.

What I need to do is to interrupt the transition of labels that re-enter the layout so the `remove()` function isn't called for them. Do you know a way how to do this?

Comment: Do you have an alternative to completely removing the elements? (It's not clear if your labels are SVG or HTML, but, if they're HTML, how about setting the `display` property to `none`?)

Comment: Transitions that are added to elements should automatically cancel earlier transitions. Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: It's basically the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mzur/b30b932d1b9544644abd) I've already linked. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azy6E/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By preparing the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Azy6E/1/) I've actually found a possible solution. It works if I delete all currently fading/exiting labels before every update like this:

```
 $svg.selectAll('.link-label.fadeout').remove();
```

See the [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azy6E/2/) (in the `updateLinkLabels()` function). Maybe you know a more elegant solution?

Comment: did you ever find a more elegant solution?